# Sumif in loop in excel Please

Tags: loops

I need help doing `Sumif` in the loop.

I have a *excel* file and in one sheet we have incoming product recorded as they delivered. We might have more than 1 delivery for on product at different dates. That means we have more than 1 row for each product with different quantities.

In another sheet we have list of all products and we need to have total quantity of each of them.

`=SUMIF('Products List'!A:A,'Incoming stock transaction'!G:G,'Incoming stock transaction'!F:F)`

But this formula just shows one quantity I think somehow I need to loop it for all the rows in Incoming Stock transaction sheet.

Please give me step by step solutionsince. I never done anything like this.

Thanks,

Sep

Comment: which column (in which) contains the products names? and which column contain the "wanted-to-be-sum" product list? and the "wanted-to-be-sum" values are located in.. ?

Comment: In the sheet Product list, column A is product name.'Products List'!A:A

Comment: In the sheet Product list column A has products name:'Products List'!A:A.     And in Incoming stock transactions sheet column F is the quantity that needs to be added up. Please use your own sample if mine is confusing.

Comment: so column G in Incoming stock transactions sheet contain the list of product names to be sum up right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 1st product name to be sum up is located in cell G2 of Incoming stock transactions sheet. Put this (your formula is already so close) :

```
=SUMIF('Products List'!A:A,'Incoming stock transaction'!G2,'Incoming stock transaction'!F:F)
```

then drag downwards.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but this formula that I have does not go row to row in incoming stock transaction sheet and sum the individual products. 
I need loop to go over each row and check the criteria if it’s the same product sum them.